# Recursion and Python dictionaries

Tags: python, recursion

I'm working through Udacity's Introduction to Computer Science Course.

For a problem set, I need to determine whether a link is reciprocal. A link from A  -> B is considered reciprocal if there is k links from B -> A.

For example. if k=2, B->A would count as a reciprocal link for node A if there is
 a path A->C->B, for some page C, (link path of length 2),
 or a direct link A-> B (link path of length 1).

Here is the "internet" I'm using for the problem. It's just a dict where the key is a URL and the value is a list of links on that page.

```
g = {'a': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'b':['a','e'], 'c':['d'], 'd':['a'], 'e':['c']}
```

Now here is the helper function I'm working on, that ideally will return a boolean depending on whether link_a -> link_b is reciprocal.

```
def is_reciprocal(g,link_a,link_b,k):
    """
    Returns True if link_a --> link_b is reciprocal
    """
    url_links = []
    print " "
    print "link_a is...",link_a
    print "link_b is...",link_b
    print "k is...",k
    print 
    if k == -1:
        return False
    for i in g[link_b]:
        if i == link_a:
            return True

    return is_reciprocal(g,link_a,g[link_b][0],k-1)
```

Here is the test value I am doing.

```
t1 = is_reciprocal(g1,'e','c',4)
```

Which prints out...

```
link_a is... e
link_b is... c
k is... 4


link_a is... e
link_b is... d
k is... 3


link_a is... e
link_b is... a
k is... 2


link_a is... e
link_b is... a
k is... 1


link_a is... e
link_b is... a
k is... 0


link_a is... e
link_b is... a
k is... -1
```

It seems that when `link_b` is `'a'`, the same `link_b` keeps getting used.

My Question:
Is there a way to recursively sort through this `dict` and make `link_b` equivalent to all values in `g['a']` while keeping the `k` value the same?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that when link_b is 'a', the same link_b keeps getting used.

This is not surprising, given that your recursive call explicitly only uses the first value:

```
return is_reciprocal(g,link_a,g[link_b][0],k-1)
```

If you want to use *all* of the values, you need to recurse on each of the values, until one of them is True. Like this:

```
for i in g[link_b]:
    if is_reciprocal(g,link_a,i,k-1):
        return True
```

However, you may notice that you now have two nearly-identical loops in a row. If you change your recursive base case to handle the `i == link_a` case for you (which is trivial: instead of returning `False` if `k == -1`, just return `link_a == link_b` if `k == 0`), then you can remove the first loop and only have the second one.